# How would you unpack a 32bit int in Python?

Tags: python, struct, unpack

I'm fairly weak with structs but I have a feeling they're the best way to do this. I have a large string of binary data and need to pull 32 of those chars, starting at a specific index, and store them as an int. What is the best way to do this?

Since I need to start at an initial position I have been playing with `struct.unpack_from()`. Based on the format table [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters), I thought the 'i' formatting being 4 bytes is exactly what I needed but the code below executes and prints "(825307441,)" where I was expecting either the binary, decimal or hex form. Can anyone explain to me what 825307441 represents?

Also is there a method of extracting the data in a similar fashion but returning it in a list instead of a tuple? Thank you

```
st = "1111111111111111111111111111111"
test = struct.unpack_from('i',st,0)
print test
```

Comment: You say you have a large string of binary data. Are you sure that's a string of ones and zeros, or do you mean something like `'\x25\x90\x14\x0d'`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `int`

```
>>> st = "1111111111111111111111111111111"
>>> int(st,2)
2147483647
>>> int(st[1:4],2)
7
```

You can slice the string any way you want to get the indices you desire. Passing `2` to `int` tells `int` that you are passing it a string in binary

Comment: It says I can accept your answer in 6 minutes but I'm leaving work now, look forward to it tomorrow morning pal